# amdgpu screen tearing

Tags: drivers, xorg

I install Ubuntu 18.04 with the amdgpu driver for my rx580 and I'm continuing to get screen tearing occasionally with windows and during video playback. I've enabled TearFree, DRI3, and a couple others in my xorg.conf.d file but none seems to have any effect.

here is my current config

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Card0"
    Driver "amdgpu"
    BusID "PCI:1:0:0"
    Option "DRI3" "3"
    Option "TearFree" "true"
    Option "VariableRefresh" "true"
EndSection
```

I've fixed this on other linux machines using compton but to my knowledge I'm not able to change the compositor used by gnome. Not sure what the next step is to trouble shoot this issue.